# PCA on repeated measures data

Tags: pca, repeated-measures

I have five dependent variables in my study. All measuring listening effort, but has different constructs (some DVs not correlated). I have measured these five variables on same subjects at 6 different SNRs at two presentation levels (total 6*2=12 conditions). I would like to run PCA on this data to reduce number of dependent variables and understand how the variables are related to each other. Can I do that considering I have repeated measures data is the question. Can anyone please help me understand why I should not run a PCA in this case if that is inappropriate?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 2 notes in case you don't get a full answer.  1) EFA sounds more applicable than PCA.  2) If you are ready to tackle more advanced techniques, look into covariance structure analysis, structural equation modeling, and confirmatory factor analysis.